# VPN broke my network connection, how can I restore it?

Tags: google-play-store, wi-fi, google-account, networking, vpn

I have a problem on my Lenovo K33a48 with Android 7.0. The problem manifests in almost all my google apps showing that there is no internet connection (Chrome, Play Store, Gmail), not syncing to my account (Google Calender) or simply crashing (Drive, Photos), see screen shots below:

[image]
[image]

If I try to do a system update (Settings->About->System Update) I also get displayed that there is no internet connection:

[image]

Nevertheless, I actually have an internet connection, both over wifi or cellular data, and can successfully send messages with Whatsapp. I think the problem cascades to other apps that can't open or keep crashing, e.g. Viber, and I think these apps are connected to my Google account.

I think the problem is the result of me installing, using and deleting a VPN app or/and me uninstalling and installing again songs on Spotify. **Anyways, can you help me restore my network connection? Can I undo any possible changes the VPN app has done? Can I reset my network settings?** I actually did in the Settings "Network Settings reset", I deleted the cache of all apps and restarted the phone, but it had no effect on the problem. Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Have you checked your network settings if there is still a VPN-profile left? Also check network proxy and DNS settings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Robert ! I managed to fix my problem by deleting the Google Play Store data and reversing updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem with the instructions written by Darren [here](https://www.technipages.com/fix-google-for-android-shows-as-offline?unapproved=1042149&moderation-hash=c61959b8bfe3e4ed38cf51c03bd8cd25#comment-1042149):

Clearing Google Play Store

1. Settings -> Apps & notifications
2. Google Play services -> Storage
3. Clear Cache & Clear Storage

Uninstalling Google Play Updates

1. Settings -> Apps & notifications
2. Google Play services
3. 3 Dots (Top-right corner) Uninstall Updates

Afterwards restart the phone and check if the problem is solved!